# netbeans SOAP operation returns null, but in SOAPUI works correctly

Tags: java, soap, netbeans

I imported wsdl-file for service into Netbeans java project and one of operations not working correctly - returns null int array. But in SOAPUI everything is ok[image]

Netbeans SOAP request is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:getDefectsQueueRequest xmlns:ns2="eds:DefectsService"><OrgID>600</OrgID></ns2:getDefectsQueueRequest></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Netbeans responce is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><getDefectsQueueResponse xmlns=""><RegNums><RegNum>174272</RegNum><RegNum>174273</RegNum><RegNum>174274</RegNum></RegNums></getDefectsQueueResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAPUI request is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eds="eds:DefectsService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <eds:getDefectsQueueRequest>
         <OrgID>600</OrgID>
      </eds:getDefectsQueueRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAPUI responce is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getDefectsQueueResponse>
         <RegNums>
            <RegNum>174272</RegNum>
            <RegNum>174273</RegNum>
            <RegNum>174274</RegNum>
         </RegNums>
      </getDefectsQueueResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There is  correct data in response, but `dqr.getRegNums().getItem()` returns null

Comment: Please edit your question to include the requests (from both Netbeans and SoapUI) as well as the responses as *text*

Comment: of course, i'm sorry

Comment: There's not much of a difference between both your requests and responses (namespace definition locations mostly) so the error is in the translation from SOAP to Java somewhere.

Comment: I see, but i use standart netbeans tools for generating soap requests. There is not any manual converting etc. So I can't understand where can be an error...

Comment: I'm just guessing now, but `getItem()` might not be the right method to call. What exactly is the return type of `dqr.getRegNums()`?

Comment: dqr.getRegNums() returns ArrayOfXsdInt type
descripted in wsdl as
<complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_int">
<sequence>
<element name="item" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>

Comment: class ArrayOfXsdInt implements 
protected List<Integer> item

Comment: `public class ArrayOfXsdInt {

    @XmlElement(type = Integer.class)
    protected List<Integer> item;

    public List<Integer> getItem() {
        if (item == null) {
            item = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        return this.item;
    }

}`

Comment: `<element name="item">` I think this is the cause of the mismatch, since the actual element in the SOAP response is `<RegNum>`, not `<item>`

Comment: thank you, it was an error in server wsdl